# Drush 5 & 8 side-by-side

Tags: drush

Is it possible have version 5 & 8 of Drush installed and to use a preferred version?

I am running an ubuntu server on which I have Drush5 installed. My attempts to remove is results in the following:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove drush -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

All attempts to deal with that issue have been unsuccessful.

So, I'm just wondering if both versions can be installed and used independently?

Comment: I would install a virtual machine for different environment...

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
alias drush5='~/drush5/drush'
alias drush6='~/drush6/vendor/bin/drush'
alias drush7='~/drush7/vendor/bin/drush'
alias drush8='~/drush8/vendor/bin/drush'
```

You will get help from [Switching Drush Versions.](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/switching-drush-versions)